# Python 3.6 / Oracle 18c / Oracle Client 12 issue (OCI-22303)

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I would like to expose here an issue I have to know if someone else had the same (and fixed it :) )

I have a Python script (3.6.1 64 bits) using cx_oracle 6.0.3. to connect ot Oracle 18c DB.
Connection is working well.
My problem is when I try to create Python variable from database type definition using gettype.

Here is my example:

```
db = cx_Oracle.connect("scott/tigger@oracle_18c")
res = db.gettype("type_employee").newobject()
```

Depending on the configuration, I have the following issue:

```
2018-10-31 15:28:15,019 - ERROR - OCI-22303: type ""."type_employee" not found
```

With Oracle 11g, the script is working well.
With Oracle 18c that depends on the Oracle client I use (I guess, it is where I am  in my investigations). When I use Oracle 11.1.0.x client it working well. the issue occurs when client is Oracle 12.

I have other tests / changes to make :

- Upgrade cx_oracle to use the version 7.0.0
- Test client Oracle 12 with Oracle 11g DB

I will do andpost here the result soon.

Does anyone had / have the same issue and can share experience / solution ?

Thanks.

**Edit 1**

I did following additional tests with configuration on Oracler 18c DB:

- Python 3.6.1 64 bits, CX-ORACLE 6.0.3, Oracle client 11 64 bits => Ok
- Python 3.6.1 64 bits, CX-ORACLE 7.0.0, Oracle client 11 64 bits => Ok
- Python 3.6.1 64 bits, CX-ORACLE 7.0.0, Oracle client 12 64 bits => NOK
- Python 3.6.1 64 bits, CX-ORACLE 6.0.3, Oracle client 12 64 bits => NOK

Using Oracle client 12 32 bits does not make sense as it is not compatible with my config.

**Edit 2**

I did following additional tests with configuration on Oracler 11g DB:

- Python 3.6.1 64 bits, CX-ORACLE 6.0.3, Oracle client 11 64 bits => Ok
- Python 3.6.1 64 bits, CX-ORACLE 7.0.0, Oracle client 11 64 bits => Ok
- Python 3.6.1 64 bits, CX-ORACLE 7.0.0, Oracle client 12 64 bits => OK
- Python 3.6.1 64 bits, CX-ORACLE 6.0.3, Oracle client 12 64 bits => OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is the command became case sensitive with Oracle Client 12 and Oracle 18c DB (Oracle 11g no issue).
If I change my code with

```
res = db.gettype("TYPE_EMPLOYEE").newobject()
```

It is working fine